# iOS8 Swift can't create view controller with xib

Tags: swift, ios8, xib

I'm using Swift and I'm fixing some bug of iOS 8. I created a view controller with .xib. For example, a view controller and a table view in it.

This how I created my .xib file.

1.I drag a tableView into the view,[image] 2.set the class of the file's owner,[image] 3.drag the view to file's owner[image] 4.drag the tableView to the file's owner[image] And I have this code in file's owner

```
class BicycleServiceInfoController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutLet tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    //other functions
    ...
}
```

But when I run this APP in iOS 8.4 and try to present this view controller, It will crash. Xcode says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". It's because tableView is nil in this code. But it works well in iOS 9.

Someone can help me?

Comment: and how do you create the viewcontroller itself ?

Answer (score 2):

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    let classString = String(describing: type(of: self))
    if Bundle.main.path(forResource: classString, ofType: "nib") == nil {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    } else {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil ?? classString, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

On iOS 8, you need call this method, on iOS 9 or later, system fixes this bug.
You can get the answer [here](http://codecloud.net/12993.html)

Comment: Is it just me, or are there too many closing braces? Or is the formatting that bad?

Comment: This is the right answer. Fixes the problem. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Tonin already provided the right answer but for everyone who struggles converting this to Swift 2.3, here you go:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    let classString = String(MyClassName)
    if NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(classString, ofType: "nib") == nil{
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    } else {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil ?? classString, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegates in the `viewWillAppear` function. Or in the interface builder.
iOS 8 has some issues of creating screens later than needed.